# How do I merge the range data of the highlighted cells of my grid's ouput?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, sparse-matrix

I am working on a game and I've come to the point where I am in need of an efficient collision detection system. At the moment, I am using a very heavy handed array of 1 and 0 to indicate a boundary.

I've written a crude grid creation tool that allows me to highlight the cells that I would like to indicate have a boundary however, I'm a bit lost in terms of how to simplify the output for quicker access.

Currently, my intention is to restructure the boundaries based on if there are consecutive highlighted cells and no entries when there are no highlighted cells. Hence the sparse matrix.

For example, assuming a cell size of 10
0,0
[_ _ *]- - -[* _ _]

I would expect my ouput to be

```
{ x: [0,30], y: [0,10] },
{ x: [60,90], y: [0,10] }
```

At the moment, I get an empty object for each cell..

This is the current iteration of my attempt to merge the range of the highlighted cells in to a single object to represent a boundary.

```
    function mergeConsecutiveCells(boundaries) {
        const mergedBoundaries = [];
       
        if (boundaries.length === 0) {
            return mergedBoundaries;
        }
       
        boundaries.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1]);
       
        let currentBoundary = boundaries[0];
       
        for (let i = 1; i < boundaries.length; i++) {

            const nextBoundary = boundaries[i];
       
            if (
                currentBoundary[1] === nextBoundary[1] &&
                currentBoundary[2] === nextBoundary[2] &&
                currentBoundary[3] === nextBoundary[3] &&
                currentBoundary[0] + cellSize === nextBoundary[0]
            ) {

                // Consecutive cells, extend the range
                currentBoundary[0] = nextBoundary[0];
            } else {
               // Non-consecutive cells, add the current boundary to the result
               mergedBoundaries.push({
                   x: { start: currentBoundary[0], end: currentBoundary[0] + cellSize },
                   y: { start: currentBoundary[1], end: currentBoundary[3] }
               });
               currentBoundary = nextBoundary;
            }
        }
        // Add the last boundary
        mergedBoundaries.push({
            x: { start: currentBoundary[0], end: currentBoundary[0] + cellSize },
            y: { start: currentBoundary[1], end: currentBoundary[3] }
        });
        return mergedBoundaries;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of trials and mucking around, I have found what seems to be a relatively straight forward solution to what I was after.

I want to say I was kind of close but not really.. XD

Here is a link to the codepen, if you were interested.
[ifaus - 2d sparse matrix - merging range data](https://codepen.io/ifaus/pen/ExrRvez)

Edit:

Inserted comments in the javascript to assist in clarifying how this solution answers my question.

```
  
// AFAIK, this only works on the X-axis at this time
  
// Combines overlapping entries in the array based on certain conditions
function combineEntries(entries, cellSize) {
  // Flag to track whether any entries were combined
  let combined = true;

  // Continue combining entries until no more combinations are possible
  while (combined) {
    combined = false;

    // Iterate through the entries
    // The entries are an Array of Objects with coordinates pulled
    // from the grid overlay of highlighted cells
      for (let i = 1; i < entries.length; i++) {
        const currentEntry = entries[i];
        const previousEntry = entries[i - 1];

        // Check if currentEntry and previousEntry can be combined
        if (canCombine(previousEntry, currentEntry, cellSize)) {
            // Merge the X and Y coordinates of previousEntry and currentEntry
            previousEntry.x = [previousEntry.x[0], currentEntry.x[1]];
            previousEntry.y = [previousEntry.y[0], currentEntry.y[1]];

            // Remove currentEntry from the array
            entries.splice(i, 1);

            // Set combined flag to true
            combined = true;
        }
    }
}

// Return the array with combined entries
return entries;
}

// Combines overlapping entries in the array based on certain conditions
function combineEntries(entries, cellSize) {
// Flag to track whether any entries were combined
let combined = true;

// Continue combining entries until no more combinations are possible
while (combined) {
    combined = false;

    // Iterate through the entries array
    for (let i = 1; i < entries.length; i++) {
        const currentEntry = entries[i];
        const previousEntry = entries[i - 1];

        // Check if currentEntry and previousEntry can be combined
        if (canCombine(previousEntry, currentEntry, cellSize)) {
            // Merge the X and Y coordinates of previousEntry and currentEntry
            previousEntry.x = [previousEntry.x[0], currentEntry.x[1]];
            previousEntry.y = [previousEntry.y[0], currentEntry.y[1]];

            // Remove currentEntry from the array
            entries.splice(i, 1);

            // Set combined flag to true
            combined = true;
        }
    }
}

// Return the array with combined entries
return entries;
}

// Checks if two entries can be combined based on specified conditions
function canCombine(entry1, entry2, cellSize) {
// Check if the entries overlap and meet certain criteria
return (
    entry1.x[1] >= entry2.x[0] &&
    entry1.y[0] === entry2.y[0] &&
    entry1.y[1] === entry2.y[1] &&
    entry2.x[0] - entry1.x[1] <= cellSize
);
}
// Checks if two entries can be combined based on specified condition
// the condition is a matrix of coordinates used for object collision
// boundaries I intend to use in a game

// Assuming a Cell size of 10
// { x: [0,10], y: [0,10] } would be Cell at location 0,0
// if a consecutive cell has an x value that is a multiple of the
// given cell size, then that entry is combined
// For example:
// { x: [0,10], y: [0,10] }
// { x: [10,20], y: [0,10] }
// would be combined as one entry in entries array
// { x: [0,20], y: [0,10] }

function canCombine(entry1, entry2, cellSize) {
// Check if the entries overlap and meet certain criteria
return (
    entry1.x[1] >= entry2.x[0] &&
    entry1.y[0] === entry2.y[0] &&
    entry1.y[1] === entry2.y[1] &&
    entry2.x[0] - entry1.x[1] <= cellSize
);
}
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

div {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

canvas {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

textarea {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px
}

table {
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

input[type=number] {
    width: 30px;
}
<div>
    <table>
    <tr><td>
        <input type="file" id="imageInput" accept="image/*">
        <label for="cellSize">Cell Size:</label>
        <input type="number" id="cellSize" value="20">
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><canvas id="gridCanvas"></canvas></td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <textarea id="outputRaw" disabled="true"></textarea>
        <textarea id="outputFinal"></textarea>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="bttnOutputFinal" value="Condense">
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).